# Should the [sound-quality] tag stand on its own, or should it be a synonym of [sound]?

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging, tag-synonyms, tag-wiki

There is a tag called [sound](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sound) and a tag called [sound-quality](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sound-quality). Should not [sound-quality](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sound-quality) be a synonym of [sound](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sound)?

Comment: I would liek to see some tag descriptions added. Otherwise the meaning (esp. a general word like "sound") will be vague and possibly incorrect.

Comment: I think it would be much more useful to get rid of `sound` and use specific tags.

Answer (score 5):

I'd say that they are not synonyms, but closely germane.

A question like

> What does define Pink Floyd's sound as 'experimental'?

would be tagged with [sound](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sound).

Whereas a question like:

> Why is the sound quality of a track reduced when it is compressed into a .mp3?

could be tagged with [sound](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sound), but [sound-quality](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sound-quality) fits better here

Comment: I agree with this, but the sound tag needs a good wiki if it is to remain

Answer (score 4):

I think `sound` is so broad that if it is allowed to stand itelf, it will inevitably encompass other topics - such as those relating to reproduction media, sounds in records, live sound etc.

`sound-quality` as a subset of those topics seems specific and useful.